# Import color variables to my styles

Tags: react-native

I want to make file with variables of my colors and then import this file to my styles.

```
button: {
 color: primarycolor
 background: primarybackground
}
```

So I can change colors only in one place.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can define a separate js file `colors.js`, that consists of the **colors object and export it**.

```
export const COLORS = {
  white: '#fff',
  black: '#000',
  // your colors
}
```

Now **import COLORS from the above file** - `import {COLORS} from './<Path>/colors.js'` in your respective file that uses the defined colors. And use it as shown below.

```
button: {
  color: COLORS.white,
  backgroundColor: COLORS.black
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's a little late. But a complete example.
Create a constant like

```
const Colors {
  tabIconDefault: '#959292',
  tabIconSelected: tintColor,
  tabBar: '#fefefe',
  errorBackground: 'red',
  errorText: '#fff',
  warningBackground: '#EAEB5E',
  warningText: '#666804',
  noticeBackground: tintColor,
  noticeText: '#fff'
};
module.exports = Colors ;
```

To use anywhere , import it like

```
const Colors = '../constants/Colors';
```

Now use it like

```
color: Colors.warningBackground
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a separate js file colors.js, that consists of the colors object and export it.
and it is easy to use anywhere. just  **import {MyColor} from './/colors.js'**

```
export const MyColor = {
  white: '#fff',
  mybackground: '#222264',
  // your colors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create file with constant colors:

```
const Colors = {
  gray: '#606060',
  white: '#FFFFFF',
  ...
};

export default Colors;
```

and use this like:

```
import Colors from '../../../Constants/Colors';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

we use one file for colors / fonts like this: `export const colors = { myColor: '#fffffff' }`

and import: `import { colorStyles } from '../../libs/styleHelpers';`

and using: `colorStyles.myColor`